# Remove #book anchor on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess, seo

I need to hide anchor on my url.

```
<a href="#book">Book</a>
```

This anchor is attached on jquery smooth scroll, when i click my url become:

www.test.it/#book

I don't want #book on my url.

is possibile?

And is possibile hide from another page?

example: www.test.it/#book to www.test.it

I see this thing on boostrap modal.

Can see here, on my site: http://www.alessandrapinto.it/

Comment: is this name url? kind of reference or in anyway you want to remove this?

Comment: When you want to remove this. onclick or document.ready and is there any id or class assigned to this anchor or its wrapper?

Comment: sorry, i need to hide, not remove, i update post.

Comment: is this anchor pointing to another page? what is the purpose of this anchor on your page

Comment: this anchor go to the middle of the page, i a landing page, http://www.alessandrapinto.it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there is # in url it will update URL by default. You need to do this with jquery if you don't want to add # in URL. Add Id your anchor I am taking this as id="name" then add class to your div till where you want to scroll your page I am taking this like class="name"

```
$("#name").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".name").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/farhanbaloch/zuf89hhq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add this:

```
e.preventDefault();

$('#myLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do other stuff when a click happens
});
```

To the end of your jQuery function. 
and then you will not see the #something in the URL.

For example, clicked anchors will not take the browser to a new URL. We can use event.isDefaultPrevented() to determine if this method has been called by an event handler that was triggered by this event.